# Persistent Chat bar between site navigations

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, navigation

I would like to have a chat which is very similar to Facebook one - whenever you navigate through facebook, the user doesn't see any chat refreshing!

You can have multiple chats while some of them are opened and when you navigate you don't notice any change or loading to this area.

I would like to get the same effect for my chat. Normally It will take more time whether to get the information back from the server.

I am also wondering where should I save the current opened chat information - on a Database, cookies, localStorage or in another place. I guess the database is the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current chat data onto the database(server) and in local storage(browser). On  document ready you can query the local storage to load recent discussions and after you've loaded those check the server for new messages that can occur while the user changed the page. Because local storage has it's limitations you have to delete old chat lines.

Comment: I am not sure if the usage of localStorage is a good choice.
It replaces only one additinal call to the database, that anyway going to take place.

Comment: You think it will be faster than simply call to the database and add it to the response html?